# ASP.NET MVC - Profile Image / File Organising

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image-processing

I'm currently building into my app a method to allow users to provide images for their profile.

As part of the upload process I'll be creating a couple of different versions of the file for use in various different places in the system.

I am not going to store the images in a database as that just doesn't make sense to me.  They will be served up by IIS and I also want to structure it in such a way that it will make migrating it to a CDN in the future a lot easier.

My current plan is to assign each user a GUID or similar unique value that will be stored in the database as part of their profile information, so something like:

```
ProfileId 1 - UserCode 628B3AF30B0F48EA8D61778084FC73C3
```

When a user uploads their profile image (or other data) I'll use the code to create a directory on the web server, for instance:

```
"~/userimages/628B3AF30B0F48EA8D61778084FC73C3/"
```

Then I'll store a few images in here like:

```
"~/userimages/628B3AF30B0F48EA8D61778084FC73C3/profilephoto160x160.jpg"
"~/userimages/628B3AF30B0F48EA8D61778084FC73C3/profilephoto25x25.jpg"
```

This should then make the process of recreating valid urls to the correct images both not hard coded anywhere nasty (like a profile image url in the database) and should make it a predictable process, something like:

```
var profileImgurl = BaseImageFolder + profile.UserCode + "profilephoto160x160.jpg"
```

I have no experience of CDN and was wondering if I'm creating any problems I'll struggle to solve later down the line when/if it gets migrated?

Does anyone see any nasty problems with this approach that I haven't thought of?

As far as I can tell people like google have a similar approach to this.

Comment: Here's a good post on Scott Hanselman's blog: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PennyPinchingVideoMovingMyWebsitesImagesToTheAzureCDNAndUsingACustomDomain.aspx

Comment: Interesting post, very useful and bang on required.  Thanks!  I'm thinking my approach is going to work just fine.